# Como substituir vírgula por ponto em um dataframe no R Studio

Tags: r

Estou importando um arquivo CSV onde os dados vem separados por vírgulas, mas preciso exportar-los no padrão do R, que é o ".".

Já tentei utilizar da função as.numeric, mas os valores desaparecem do dataframe, e a função str_replace_all retorna o erro " argument is not an atomic vector; coercing"

Dataframe com os dados

```
1   252  2,0056
2   504  2,0881
3   756  2,4613
4   1260 2,8715
5   2520 3,3215
6   3024 3,4256
7   252  5,2604
8   504  5,7646
9   756  6,2504
```

Comment: Pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(dados)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(dados, 20))`? Nota: `dados` é o nome da base, por exemplo de um data.frame. O link não nos dá acesso aos dados.

Comment: Olá, inclui os dados, obrigado pela sugestão.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma maneira de substituir as vírgulas decimais por pontos é com `as.numeric/sub`.
Como o dataframe da pergunta não está muito claro, não tenho a certeza se a primeira coluna é mesmo uma coluna ou se são os `row.names`, vou primeiro determinar em que colunas há vírgulas. Essas colunas terão um valor`TRUE` no vetor `cols`.

```
cols <- sapply(dados, function(x) any(grepl(",", x)))
dados[cols] <- lapply(dados[cols], function(x) as.numeric(sub(",", ".", x)))
```

Outra maneira, quanto a mim melhor, é evitar o problema lendo os dados com o argumento `dec = ","` que muitas funções do R de leitura de dados têm.

```
dados2 <- read.table(text = "
1   252  2,0056
2   504  2,0881
3   756  2,4613
4   1260 2,8715
5   2520 3,3215
6   3024 3,4256
7   252  5,2604
8   504  5,7646
9   756  6,2504
", dec = ",")
```

Isto chega para as decimas estarem separadas por pontos:

```
identical(dados, dados2)
#[1] TRUE
```

**Dados.**

```
dados <- read.table(text = "
1   252  2,0056
2   504  2,0881
3   756  2,4613
4   1260 2,8715
5   2520 3,3215
6   3024 3,4256
7   252  5,2604
8   504  5,7646
9   756  6,2504
")
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função `read.csv2()` que lê os arquivos de número separados por vírgula ou pode usar `as.numeric(sub(",", ".", Input, fixed = TRUE))`